# Question on Vlan's

Tags: hp

I have 2 radio uplinks going to the same building, I have data and voice vlans, can it be setup on the system so it does not create a loop when it is connected to the same switch's at the ends? I want to run voice on one connection and data on the other

Comment: Why are the two vLans connected at L2?! They should have completely different broadcast domains, IP Subnets, and would not create a loop. The whole point of a vLan is to separate the data.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [Spanning Tree Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) what you're looking for?

Comment: STP has the unfortunate habit of shutting down every parallel link except one.  The inventor of STP has moved on to create TRILL (TRansparent Interconnection of Lots of Links), which load-balances parallel links and is woven into the Ethernet "fabrics" now being marketed for data center switching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Connect one radio at each site to a port on your voice vlan, the other to a port on your data vlan. Make sure it's that way at both ends and you'll be fine...no conflict unless the radios can't work as isolated pairs.  For a detailed answer, need to know more about your radio links and the switches behind them.